# Angular get request is taking data from cache in IE 11

Tags: angular, ajax, get

get(config): Observable {

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  ...config.headers,
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
});

const url = config.url;
let response = this.httpClient.get(url, { headers, params : config.params });

return response;
```

}

I have used the solutions which I got added headers{ 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache','Pragma': 'no-cache',}
for the AJAX calls.

Comment: And _what_ exactly is your question now?

Comment: The get call is taking data from cache in IE 11. It's working fine in Chrome. I have added the headers but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/777 can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following header to your request:

```
{'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'}
```